how do I fix extra blank space left within my pages and at the end of page? i have tried various mathods but none worked
i have tried using \flushbottom, making sure that content in math mode is not too long, and using vspace(-1cm) but nothing worked. Here is the code of my main file:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,xspace}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\LARGE\sffamily\scshape\color{blue}}
\ChNumVar{\Large\selectfont\color{blue}}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sffamily\color{blue}}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=BlueGreen}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1.5}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1.5em}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{2.5em}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.4em}

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em} % Adjust the width for section numbers
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{4em} % Adjust the width for subsection numbers
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{1.5em} % Add space before section title

% Color for sections
\definecolor{chapterblue}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
{\thesection}{1em}{}
%=======================================%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem*{notation*}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}



I had already fixed it fit by making sure content within mathmode like [], align, etc is not too long to fit on the current page. Otherwise I would break it down in defferent tags. But my supervisor asked me to increase the font size and the problem started againg. But now nothing is working. Any help will be appreciated.

\raggedbottom will be better in your case.

You have not shown any relevant code, but the image suggests that you are using \flushbottom and that the top of the next page has a large non breakable item.

Im not using \flushbottom anywhere. And i tried using \raggedbottom but it didn't work.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I used \allowdisplaybreaks in my preamble and it worked. It automatically adjusted required page breaks within \begin{align}...\end{align}. It already contained \raggedbottom in my preamble on above suggestions but idk if it's playing any role as initially i didn't worked but I didn't remove as i don't want to risk it now.
